# Unusable space when creating Ubuntu partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I 'm installing Ubuntu with a USB stick in a Windows machine. When creating partitions I can only create / partition and /swap partition. I'm unable create the /home partition from rest free space as it displays as unusable. I know that similar questions have been asked. However as I can see there's only one primary partition and others are logical. Can you please help me to proceed with Ubuntu installation as I fairly new to those things.

[image]

```
/dev/sda
  free space 105MB
  /dev/sda1 ntfs 41838 Windows
  /dev/sda5 ntfs 41943
  /dev/sda6 ntfs 52427
  /dev/sda7 ntfs 61311

  /dev/sda3 ext4 /  14999MB
  /dev/sda4 swap    4000MB
  Unusable          33429
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, that Ubuntu installer wants to create one primary partition and then rest of partitions as logical on the extended one. It would be overkill to install both operating system again, I don't recommend it. Instead, prepare partitions for Ubuntu in the Windows partitioning tool (the same you take screenshot from). Don't assign drive letter nor format them, just leave them as RAW partitions. They will be visible in the Ubuntu installer's partitioning tool and you can format them and set their mount points there.

Answer (score -1):

Partitioning tools in the installer often messes up primary/extended partition recognition.

You should prepare the partitions in a separate tool before installing both operating systems. It always works.

Comment: I would actually say the opposite. The windows partitioning tool has imaginary limits, and makes inappropriate decisions when it doesn't have to (grouping partitions, creating extended ones, ...). `fdisk` is clearly more reliable.

Comment: Possible if you are talking about graphical partitioning tool in Windows. But I found Microsoft command line tool `diskpart` the most reliable and user friendly tool to manipulate partitions.

Comment: @guntbert Actually, no. Both "*it does some mess*" and "*it always works*" sounded amazingly simplistic to me. While the other answer provides actual guidelines, I'd rather see this one as a comment. Of course, the voting system will take everyone's opinion into consideration :) I'll skip on the *best partition tool* debate though, obviously opinion-based.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith, I was then mislead by the word "opposite". Partitioning tools in the **installer** sometimes create surprising results as opposed to the standard tools used from an installed system (or even a live CD/USB.